# Objective-C How can I test an if statement after a delay?

Tags: objective-c, delay, nstimer

I know in Objective-C you're able to use timers and delays. However both of these execute the block of code first before delaying.

Is there a way to delay the actual execution of the method?

Basically I am looking to do this...

```
int number = 1;
//delay 5 seconds
//then use an if statement

if(number == 1)
{
    NSLog(@"number still equals 1");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"number no longer equals 1");
}
```

I'm testing proximities, so I'd be testing if someone is still `CLProximityNear` to the beacon after 5 seconds execute some kind of code.

Comment: "However both of these execute the block of code first before delaying."  What???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Grand Central Dispatch and the dispatch_after function.